# Can I cache mp3 files using service worker?

Tags: service-worker

Is there any restriction on what kind of files could be cached by a service worker?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out https://samdutton.github.io/samples/service-worker/prefetch-video/ which works around this issue by manually created ranged responses.

Fixing this is gated on figuring out what browsers should be doing here, and updating the service worker spec if needed.

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37614302/6773912

Comment: Works around which issue?

Comment: Thanks ! this was what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are no restrictions on the kind of files you can cache.