# Angular 7 service worker caching audio file causes range header issues on safari

Tags: javascript, angular, caching, audio, service-worker

In my angular app there is an issue with the range request header for any `new audio(audio src here)` request on safari. When requesting audio from a server the duration of the audio file is returned as normal. However, when requesting the audio from the service worker it returns the audio duration as Infinite.

I've had a google around and Safari apparently has this issue where it sets the range header for cached media files to 'bytes=0-1' which is where the issue lies as shown below: 
[image]

Is there a way in angular to intercept a `new audio(audio src here)` request and modify the headers or somehow exclude any media requests from the service worker caching policy?

My current service worker config is below:

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/img/logo.png",
          "/assets/img/no-internet-icon.jpg",
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `Content-Range` in the response header of your audio response.

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/37614302/11339645